# How to change array string into integers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, integer

This is my function;

```
$(function () { 
    var MonthlyGDV = gdv.join();
    console.log(MonthlyGDV);
}
```

And the `MonthlyGDV` string array data shown below;

> 28248151.73,42523366.46,70004655.23,74813782.00,56187209.95,179375020.00,82134679.22,88889695.50,77362881.39,92529275.00,113701677.00,220298515.30

Can I ask how to change each element into an integer so I use the data in HighChart.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt(gdv[i])` to change string to integer.

```
var MonthlyGDV = gdv.join();
console.log(MonthlyGDV);

var intArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < gdv.length;i++) {
   intArray.push(parseInt(gdv[i]));
}
```

Comment: u mean I should do like this ?   => parseInt(MonthlyGDV)

Comment: @ Wei Kang, can you accept the answer if you think its useful.